# Expected declaration in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var y1Val: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var y2Val: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var x1Val: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var x2Val: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var m: NSTextField!

    var y1 = Double.self; y1Val; //Expected declaration on y1Val
}
```

I'm trying to get a small app to run on my Mac but can't seem to assign variables to the input text fields.

P.S. I'm new to GUI but not Swift.

Comment: The line `var y1 = Double.self; y1Val;` make little sense. What are you trying to do with that line?

Comment: this was my best effort on trying to assign y1(a variable) to the input text that is coming from y1Val

Comment: `var y1 = y1Val.doubleValue`. But you can't just stick that code where it is. You would need to access that value after the user has entered some text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `NSViewController` and `NSTextField`, it appears you're writing a macOS app. Given that, the easiest way to sync the `y1` variable to the content of your text field is to use Cocoa bindings. To do this, declare your variable with `@objc` and `dynamic`, like so:

```
@objc dynamic var y1: Double = 0 // Or whatever the initial value should be
```

Then, in your xib or storyboard file, select your text field, go to the Bindings Inspector, and bind the `Value` binding to your view controller ("File's Owner" if it's a xib, "View Controller" if it's a storyboard), and set `Model Key Path` to `y1` (leave `Controller Key` at the default `selection`). Now, with no additional code, your text field's content will be synced to the `y1` variable; if the text field's value changes, the variable will change, and vice-versa.

Comment: thank you this seems to work